# EXCEL- Rank values in pivot table based on filter of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of customer accounts which needs to be ranked based on the revenue. But I want them to be ranked for each market. Basically in the pivot table Market is the filter.I want to use rank function and dynamically generate a rank based on the market filtered.Could anyone suggest a way to do this?.Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details like what is issue and what you have tried to resolve. Please post the code having issue.

Comment: Pivot table contains 2columns,CustomerNames,Revenue.and filter for Mkts.When I select each Market,corresponding customernames &revenue is seen.I want to rank those customers based on revenue. I dont want to select the market and then rank them,instead I would like to rank the customers for based on the market they are present in as the number of customers in each market varies. For example, If there are 100 customers in North America region,I would like to rank them by taking the revenue from that region in to account.ForEurope,the no of customers is60.rank these 60 based on customers-europe

Comment: Hope I was clear,Please let me know if it is not clear,I can explain again in much more broader fashion.Thanks.